# How to tack browser Manual change in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I am developing a application in Silverlight. I want to restrict, when user changes the url directly from address bar. How to stop this.

Comment: Imagine how crappy the internet would be if you could do this. If you ended up on a spammy site you would have to shut down your browser to get off of it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of stopping that. You are not in a position to control the user like that. You could use the `beforeonload` event of the `window` object in JavaScript to present a warning to the user.

```
<script>
    window.onbeforeunload = function() {
        return "You should not leave this page.";
    };
</script>
```