# How to prevent manual tampering of Url in Silverlight 4.0?

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to tack browser Manual change in silvelight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8062539/how-to-tack-browser-manual-change-in-silvelight)

I am developing an application in Silverlight 4.0. In my application, I have a menu. When user click on the menu, then it navigates to the appropriate request page. If user changes the url from address bar manually, and navigate on the changes url. then I want to restrict that type of request.

Please help how to do this.

Comment: If you need to clarify a question, please edit it. Don't post a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

The only thing you can do is validate the request against the identity of the user and grant/deny access based on that.

Answer (score 0):

Place a Session value in  the page and check whether the session is empty or not in other pages.If session is empty then don't load the page.(Make the session value as empty in the current page.)If User wants to go to next page by link or navigation then,assign any value to the session in those click events.
this may look like this.

```
this.Session["UserId"] = "";
```

In all other pages ,

```
If(Session["UserId"] == "")
{
   Response.ExpiresAbsolute = (DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
   Response.AddHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
   Response.AddHeader("cache-control", "private");
   Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
}
```

I hope this will work.Please check

Comment: I am working in Silverlight, Above code will work in silverlight or Not. let it me know, will it work or not in silverlight

Comment: I am not sure Aman.I just suggested you the logic.Please check once.

Comment: I think so session does not work in silverlight.

Comment: If Session doesn't work place a variable and check that one.